# Property return value error

Tags: vb.net, properties

I have a class classed class1.vb, it has a public property named prop1 with a get and a set clause. I add one to the value passed in the set clause and in the get clause return the value variable as determined in the set clause. However, I get an error on the variable in the get clause...

```
Public Property prop1()
    Get 
        Return value 
    End Get 
    Set (value)
        value = value +1
    End Set 
End Property
```

any ideas?

Comment: What is prop1?  Looks like an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the type of the property and try changing your `value` variable to something else, since  the `Set` is using it's own local variable of the same name:

```
Private myValue As Integer

Public Property prop1() As Integer
  Get 
    Return MyValue 
  End Get 
  Set (ByVal value As Integer)
    MyValue = value
  End Set
End Property
```

Comment: I am still coming up with this same error after I changed to this...?